# Adaptive height for UITableViewCell containing an UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have an `UITableView` (let's call it `table1`) which contains static rows. The first row contains another `UITableView` (`table2`), populated dynamically from an XML file on the internet, which is completed **after** the cell is being created, because asynchronous. **`table2` is created and added to cell's `contentView` only once the request is done** (else an error text is prompted as cell's label).

`table2` is made of collapsed sections that are expanded when interacted, which thus do change the `contentSize`/`height` of the `table2`.

What I want to achieve is to make the cell of `table1` resize dynamically at 2 key points: *1* when the web request is done, which means when the table is created and added as subview, and *2* when a section of `table2` is interacted, which makes the height of `table1` change; `table1` cell should follow and do exactly the same height variation.

I've searched everywhere and tried tons of things, but nothing ever worked, and I've been stuck for days.

Here's what I've tried:

- Overriding (`estimated`)`heightForRowAtIndexPath:`: useless as it's only called once and before `table2` is added
- Changing `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `estimatedRowHeight`: done by default
- Using `NSLayoutConstraint`s, within `updateConstraints` or after `table2` creation
- Playing with `intrinsicContentSize` and `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize:`
- Using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

...but nothing worked, and I feel I've tried everything

About the constraints, I tried something like:
`table2.top` = `contentView.top` = `cell.top` (same for leading & trailing)
`cell.bottom` = `contentView.bottom` = `table2.bottom` (also with height)

---

**EDIT 1:**
**My code:**

```objectivec
// Cell
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.openSection = -1; // reports which section of table2 is open
        SPDSpinnerView *spinner = [[SPDSpinnerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]; // view with UIActivityIndicator & text
        spinner.label.text = @"Loading...";
        [self addSubview:spinner];
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self loadDataWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
            // Remove spinner
            for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
                if ([view isKindOfClass:[SPDSpinnerView class]]) [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            // Handle result
            if (success) {
                // Add table view when done
                self.table2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
                self.table2.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [self.table2 registerClass:[SPDChangelogHeaderView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"headerView"]; // custom tappable header for collapsible sections
                self.table2.scrollEnabled = NO;
                self.table2.delegate = self;
                self.table2.dataSource = self;
                self.table2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
                [UIView transitionWithView:self.contentView duration:.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                    [self.contentView addSubview:self.table2];
                    // FIXME: fit table2 in cell
                } completion:nil];
            } else {
                self.textLabel.text = @"Error loading data";
            }
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

// delegates, touch handler for table2, and data loader
```

(nothing else related to my problem aside from usual code)

---

**EDIT 2:**
"Mockups:"
[What it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSToc.png)

[What I want it to be at step 1 (after data loading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKyad.png)

[What I want it to be when inner sections are collapsed or expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kFkG.png)

*For (2) and (3), red lines are the height I want for both `table2` and the cell. In this MRE, `table2` overlaps the rest of `table1` but I want of course to keep the same spacing between cells of `table1`, `table1` must grow as the cell does.*

---

Thank you!

Comment: Embedding a table view in a table view cell is inherently problematic. Depending on the specifications of what you're trying to do, there may be better approaches, such as custom views in a stack view or multiple sections in the table view. If you put together a [mre] that **accurately** reflects your end goal, it will be much easier to offer help.

Comment: I guess that's because it's such problematic to do that there isn't already a comprehensive solution anywhere. Is it really **that** hard to expand or collapse an `UITableViewCell` anywhere we want?  
I think I'm gonna have to find a whole other solution, but I would have loved to reproduce what I had in mind.

Comment: It's not difficult to expand/collapse cells. What it wounds like you're running into is that you are embedding a table view - **which has no height** - in a cell. There is probably a better approach, but if you really want to do that you can subclass `UITableView` and have it control its own height. Of course, you end up throwing away the cell reuse efficiency by doing so. Again, a [mre] would make it much easier to give you some direction.

Comment: I've added some code as you requested. But do you mean that if I wrap my `table2` into a stack view as you previously mention, and if I put this stack view containing my table into my cell of `table1`, it could solve my issue?

Comment: No... you are adding a table view to your cell, but you're not giving it a Height. Can `table2` have a couple hundred rows? Will it have a max of 10 rows? You say  `table1` has "static rows" ... what does that look like? Does it really need to be a table view? Maybe try mocking up what you envision to be your layout... it's very possible that a multi-section table will be a better route to go ... or maybe you don't even need that "outer" table to begin with.

Comment: I added mockups. Thanks for you help.

Comment: That looks like it could be done with a standard table view and multiple sections?

Comment: Yes of course but it would be much prettier if I could manage to make it like that, and it's frustrating to only not be able to do it because of a cell height you see

Comment: I still think you're fighting against the default functionality of a table view... take a look at this - I think it is close to what you're going for: https://github.com/DonMag/SubSectionsDemo --- if you really, *really*, ***really*** want to use a cell with an embedded table view, I can give you an example of that approach.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted!! Your example app is perfect (I only changed the table view style to grouped to fit my needs). I mentioned an inner table because I didn't think about nested sections, but this looks perfect. If you don't, I'm gonna post a detailed answer as soon as I've fully understood your approach. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Glad it looks like it can work for you. For future reference.... try not to get so locked-in to an approach that isn't working, that you discard options/suggestions for other approaches. See `XY Problem`

Comment: I know, that's one of my weaknesses... I'm the kind of person that has an idea, does it, and when it's almost done, figures out that they can't continue and have to redo everything with another approach haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the kind help of [DonMag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag), I've reconsidered my issue. My idea was to embed a whole table in my cell: instead, they proposed to use **subsections**. A link is worth thousand words:

[github.com/DonMag/SubSectionsDemo](https://github.com/DonMag/SubSectionsDemo)

If you want further explanation on how it works, let me explain. Basically, the idea is to create 2 kinds of cells you want to "simulate" your embedded table with: (sub)headers & (sub)cells. They will both be cells belonging to the section of your `table1`, with 2 different looks.
Then, to recreate the collapsing effect, you have to handle cells selection but *only for subheader cells* in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.
Cell collapsing is done by reloading data and then adding to `table1` section, during the reloading, only subcells that are not virtually collapsed, and all the subheaders.
Hope it was clear enough to help you understand the code above on GitHub.

Unfortunately I won't be using this as-is because I do use a special subclass of `UITableViewController` whose behavior is slightly different. I'll try to adapt as much DonMag's code as possible to my use, but the idea by itself will greatly help me.